# Consulta con animacion con css libreria animate.css

Tags: javascript, css

estoy usando la librería animate.css, me resulta muy practica y ya he puesto algunas animaciones a mi web, lo único que me falta es que la animación se ejecute solo cuando el elemento se muestre en pantalla y no cuando se recarga la pagina.
La librería es la siguiente:

https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

Gracias!

Lo utilizo de esta manera:
Al elemento que quiero animar le asigno una classe: class="animated fadeInDown fast"

y el css es el siguiente:

```css
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que tienes para poder replicar el problema que tienes.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes [cambiar las classes de css que tienen asignadas un elemento de html](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

```
function miFuncion() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById("miBoton");
  elemento.classList.add("fadeOut");
}
```

Y puedes hacer ese cambio en respuesta a un evento:

```
  <button id="miBoton" onClick="miFuncion()" class="animate">miBoton</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, y para que el evento sea solo que se muestre en la pantalla como seria eso?